# React component masquerading as a function

Tags: reactjs

Can anyone please help me understand what is going on here in some code I need to refactor.

I have a component which looks pretty ordinary such as this:

```
export default class MyContainer extends PureComponent {
  //props
  //state
  //render()
  //etc.
}
```

This is then passed in as props to another component like this:

```
export class ParentContainer
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Tabs
          home={MyContainer}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

but what's got me confused is inside Tabs, it requires a function.

```
export default class Tabs extends PureComponent {
   static propTypes = {
    home: func.isRequired,
  }
}
```

This raises many questions for me:

What does this `home={MyContainer}` do? Just instantiate a component inline with all default props maybe? I haven't seen that syntax before. And why is this component acting as a function. Is there something going on behind the scenes like react is implicitly converting the component to the render() function perhaps?

If I try instantiate it in the 'normal' way so that I can add some new props i.e. `{<MyContainer />}` I get a runtime error saying that Tabs is expecting a function? Should I just change the Tabs to expect an object to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does this `home={MyContainer}` do?

The component `MyContainer` is passed as a prop to `Tabs` component. `Tabs` will in turn decide when to render `MyContainer` component.

> And why is this component acting as a function. Is there something going on behind the scenes like react is implicitly converting the component to the render() function perhaps?

React Components are ES6 classes. All classes in JavaScripts are `functions` by nature. The `class` syntax is just a syntactic sugar to define a function. That's why `home: func.isRequired` means, a component should be passed to `home` prop.

> If I try instantiate it in the 'normal' way so that I can add some new props i.e. {< MyContainer />} I get a runtime error saying that Tabs is expecting a function? Should I just change the Tabs to expect an object to get this working?

No. When you pass `{< MyContainer />}` to `home`, you are trying to execute the component while setting it in `home` prop. You should only pass the reference to the `home` prop like this `home={MyContainer}`

Comment: So, is there any way now to pass in a reference to a callback function in the parent component ? I really need this child component to be able to alter the state of the parent e.g pseudo code {MyContainer onSwitch=this.onSwitch}

Comment: You can try `home={() => < MyContainer propName={'value'} />}`